# Are Facebook SDK and Android Facebook app linked?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm just starting to use [Facebook SDK for Android](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) and I'm wondering if there is a way to link it to the actual Facebook android app itself.

What I mean is when I'm logged in in Facebook official app, I would like Facebook.isSessionValid() to return true and not get into the login with password process.

Is that possible or am I dreaming of an unfeasible thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. The Facebook SDK uses the app if it's installed for authentication. Otherwise it falls back to a `WebView` based one. This way you don't have to deal with usernames and passwords (and can't get them even if you wanted). It won't ask the user for credentials if he is already signed into the app though.

The user still has to confirm permissions and allow your app specifically for safety reasons.
It would be pretty bad if every app could abuse your Facebook account in the background without asking for permission first.

Comment: oh alright. So in my case Facebook.isSessionValid() might return false because I haven't authorized the app yet. Appart from that, i'm logged in.

Comment: Yeah you have to authorize your app first. Your session can turn invalid later though when it times out. But w/o auth you won't get any valid session ever.